# How to check if an int variable is even or odd by "looking" at the last digit of its binary value?

Tags: c++, performance

How it is possible to check if one integer number stored in a variable is even or odd, looking at its last digit?
(I've already seen many answers determining it by the reminder doing a modulo operation,
but, I mean, since a binary-number's last digit can be 0 xor 1,
and assumed that it is 0, the number is even, else the number is odd, wouldn't it be much faster to simply look at its last digit?)

Comment: You can use the modulo operation to look at the last digit of its binary value.

Comment: Is the integral type `signed` or `unsigned`?

Comment: `%` operator will do that for you without any further headaches. The compilers are pretty good at optimizing these things.

Comment: For both the cases, what would change? @Bathsheba

Comment: Integers *don't have* digits. *Representations of* integers have digits. There's nothing to "look at". You can *compute* what the last digit is - which is *exactly what the modulo trick (or bit-masking trick, etc.) actually does*. What you are asking for is like if I told you my name is Karl and you wanted to *see* the "K" that was somehow *part of* me.

Comment: _" wouldn't it be much faster to simply look at its last digit?"_ it's unclear what you think "look at its last digit" means.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
bool even = !(x % 2);
```

to test evenness for any integral type `x`. You *could* use flashy XOR tricks but then you are doing the compiler's job, not your job. The compiler will make the appropriate optimisation. Yes XOR is normally an extremely fast machine-level instruction, to the point you see REG XOR REG to set REG to 0 when looking at generated assembly, rather than a write to 0.

The correct way using XOR is to write

```
bool even = (x & 1) ^ ((-1 & 1) | ((x < 0) ? 0 : 1));
```

assuming `x` is a `signed` type. Any other way and you are assuming something about the complementing scheme of `x`. You can't assume 2's complement until C++20.

Comment: If I was 10 years younger, I would ask why. Now I am just going to marvel at the Baroque nature of the expression and bow to your wisdom :-)

Comment: At least odd check is more straightforward: `bool odd = (x & 1) ^ ((x < 0) ? (1 - (-1 & 1)) : 0);` ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming two's complement (or unsigned) numbers, which are guaranteed by C++20, and were  nearly ubiquitous before:

```
bool even = !(x & 1);
```

Comment: Just helpin' out. Although I had to double-check: https://ideone.com/TnKtA7

Comment: @Bathsheba Ouch, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> wouldn't it be much faster to simply look at its last digit?

Checking last bit will be <s>faster</s> **not slower** than calculating `x % 2` and comparing that to `0`.

However, your compiler will most certainly do that optimization. So write your code in a manner that is easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: "will be faster" on all possible hardware, platforms, compilers and past/future versions of all these. That's a bold claim ;-). I'd rather say "probably won't be slower".